# Powershell $env:path changing depending on how it is opened (PowerToys Run)?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, path, powershell-7.0, powertoys

I recently started using [PowerToys Run](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run) and I've noticed that I can no longer use some commands when launching Powershell (7.2.6) via PTR vs just running it out of the start menu.

Turns out, my $env:path is different depending on which way I launch Powershell. Why is my path different, and what is the best way that I can make sure that I have access to the same paths no matter how I open PWSH?

Comment: Why not just use your profile(s) ***'C:\Users\...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profiles'/'C:\Users\...\Documents\PowerShell'*** to set things as you wish regardless of which version of PowerShell you launch or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child process inherits the environment of its parent.
It seems like PowerToys Run modifies its PATH variable before executing
PowerShell.

The only way to avoid it might be to set up a script that will be always run
when PowerShell is started.

This is described in the post
[Run Powershell script when you open Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/886951/run-powershell-script-when-you-open-powershell).

Your script for PowerShell could then set the PATH to your preferred path.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  New to Powershell, so this was a big help.

I added a new profile (as I didn't have one, and then I used 

`$env:path +=`

to update my path every time I launch.